# MongoDB. Change Type from Object Id

Tags: mongodb

I have collection Shirt, which have a field "Images" which is currently a reference to another collection:

```
...
    images: {
        type: [{
            type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
            ref: 'Image'
        }]
    },
```

I need to change that type to an object like this:

```
const ImageSchema = new Schema({
    cloudImage: String,
    imageName: String,
});

 ...
    images: {
        type: ImageSchema
    },
```

The problem: In my database I already have about 1000 documents with the ObjectId's stored in image field.
Since there are not many documents, I decided to perform a loop over all documents and transform the data and store it again in the new model structure.
The problem is that when I get the "images" from "shirt" mongo returns this:

```
[ { _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
    id: <Buffer 5f 8a fe 45 0b cc ae 21 5a 9f 2c 6b> } ]
```

And the error:

```
CastError: Cast to ObjectId failed for value "{ _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
  id: <Buffer 5f 8a fe 45 0b cc ae 21 5a 9f 2c 6b> }" at path "_id" for model "Image"
```

I guess this is happening because there is an ObjectId stored, and I changed the collection field image to another type. If I put again [ObjectId] in type, it returns the id.

My script to perform this operation is:

```
async function updateShirtImages() {

    const shirts = await Shirt.find({});

    shirts.forEach(async (shirt) => {

        
        const imagesArray = shirt.images;
        console.log(IMAGES ARRAY =>, imagesArray)
        //Result: IMAGES ARRAY ==> [ { _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
        //id: <Buffer 5f 8a fe 45 0b cc ae 21 5a 9f 2c 6b> } ]
         
        imagesArray.forEach(async (image) => {
            console.log(image)
            const databaseImage = await Image.findOne({ _id: image }); // Here the error
            const updatedDataImageShirt = {
                cloudImage: databaseImage.cloudImage,
                imageName: databaseImage.imageName,
            };
            shirt.images.push(updatedDataImageShirt);
            await shirt.save();
        })
    })
}
```

THANK YOU!

EDIT ==> Solved issue, applying .lean() when I perform the find() method in all shirts, in order to get a POJO.

Comment: Can you print `shirt.images`, your findOne function expects an ObjectId, but I believe something else is being passed into that

Comment: I already edited the post adding the log. It returns that when I changed the field, I mean in the model it is not a reference (ObjectId) to model image, but it is embedded now. For testing, I changed back again the model to the reference and it return ok the ObjectId("asdasdas")

Comment: Glad, you solved your issue

Answer (score 0):

Check if the images ObjectId [`is valid`](https://github.com/Automattic/mongoose/issues/1959) before querying the images collection,

```
async function updateShirtImages() {
    try {
        const shirts = await Shirt.find({}).exec();
        for (const shirt of shirts) {
            for (const image of shirt.images) {
                if (image && mongoose.Types.ObjectId.isValid(image)) {
                    const databaseImage = await Image.findOne({ _id: image }).exec();
                
                    if (databaseImage !== null) {
                        const updatedDataImageShirt = {
                            cloudImage: databaseImage.cloudImage,
                            imageName: databaseImage.imageName,
                        };
                    
                        shirt.images.push(updatedDataImageShirt);
                        await shirt.save();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        
    } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
        throw err;
    }
}
```

Comment: Checking that, I am avoiding the error, but the document is not being changed, since it never enters to the if because it is never a valid object Id but this [ { _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
    id: <Buffer 5f 8a fe 45 0b cc ae 21 5a 9f 2c 6b> } ]

Comment: @nacho What is `image` can you console.log it ?

Comment: the log is [ { _bsontype: 'ObjectID',
    id: <Buffer 5f 8a fe 45 0b cc ae 21 5a 9f 2c 6b> } ] 
In the database I stored it as ObjectId. But now in the model I changed it to another type. So I think when it performs the find(), it does not find that is a reference but another type and returns that

Comment: @nacho it seems a valid objectId

Comment: mm but it is not entering in the if...I made some logs..is there a way to change [ { _bsontype: 'ObjectID', id: <Buffer 5f 8a fe 45 0b cc ae 21 5a 9f 2c 6b> } ]  to the actual human legible id?..like ["5f8afe450bccae215a9f2c6b"]

Comment: @nacho you could do `image.toString()` it gives a string version of the ObjectId

Comment: I tried and and I got imagesArray [ '{ _bsontype: \'ObjectID\',\n  id: <Buffer 5f 8b 16 26 da 07 f5 2a ca 14 85 25> }' ]... :(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/223208/discussion-between-kunal-mukherjee-and-nacho).